# В теле php-страницы выдать 404 ошибку, если неверные get-параметры

Tags: php, get, error404

Есть сайт на php 5.6, хостинг на nic.ru (RU-CENTER) - структура каталогов на хостинге у nic.ru такая:
mysite.ru\docs - в этой папке хранится весь сайт.
mysite.ru\errordocs - хранятся html-страницы с ошибками, например mysite.ru\errordoc\404.html - страница, отображаемая пользователю, в случае возникновения 404 ошибки.

Стоит задача, если в строке запроса передано неверное значение параметра, то необходимо выводить пользователю 404 ошибку т.е. страницу 404.html. Как это сделать?
Например, если пользователь в браузере набрал неправильное значение параметра www.mysite.ru/art.php?art=unknownvalue выдавать 404-ошибку т.к. у параметра art значения могут быть только art1 и art2.

Ниже даю шаблон моей страницы
`
...

...
  
  ...

```
 case ("art1");
 include_once('arts/art1.php');
 break;

 case ("art2");
 include_once('arts/art2.php');
 break;           

 endswitch;
  ?>
```

...

`

Comment: Нужно принимать переменную, после, анализировать значение и если не удовлетворяет требованиям, то делать `redirect()` на страницу 404 по другому адресу на том же домене!

Comment: можно пример - как это должно выглядеть в моем коде

Comment: Просто вставьте в вашу конструкцию case - `default: redirect('/errordoc/404.html');` в конце как последнее условие. Подробнее о конструкции [здесь](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?sc).

Comment: RifmaMan, спасибо за информацию. Добавил в default: redirect('/errordoc/404.htm') выдается ошибка Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect() in Z:\home\mysite.ru\www\art.php on line 40. PHP-код располагается внутри <html><html/> или же данный код php нужно разместить перед <html>? нужно ли в default: перед вызовом redirecta вызывать header со статусом 404?